Stream handling "exceptions"
While using Redis Stream, I encountered an issue where the consumer faced an exception while consuming, leading to the cancellation of subscription by the StreamMessageListenerContainer. I found that this was due to cancelSubscriptionOnError being triggered when encountering an exception. However, StreamReadRequest is package-private, so I have no way to modify cancelSubscriptionOnError. I'd like to inquire about how to handle consumer exceptions during consumption to maintain the subscription intact.
I don't know how to do

You can create StreamReadRequest object with own implementation of cancelOnError method. And then create a container based on this configuration. In the example I just simply skip any errors occurring in the listener.
    @Bean
    public Subscription subscription(
            final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory
    ) {
        var streamOffset = StreamOffset.create(
                streamKey, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()
        );
        var options = StreamMessageListenerContainer
                .StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions
                .builder()
                .pollTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .build();
        var container = StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(
                connectionFactory, options
        );
        var streamReadRequest = StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest
                .builder(streamOffset)
                .consumer(Consumer.from(streamKey, streamKey))
                .cancelOnError(t -> false) // skip errors
                .autoAcknowledge(false)
                .build();
        var subscription = container.register(streamReadRequest, streamListener);
        container.start();
        return subscription;
    }

